# Problems with Masonry in Rails, using Twitter Bootstrap.

Tags: jquery, css, ruby-on-rails, twitter-bootstrap

Here is a JSFiddle of what my site looks like currently: https://jsfiddle.net/4u4xx1yg/

There is an empty space between divs, which is why I'm trying to use Masonry to make the divs appear like this:

[image: evenly spaced divs with twitter bootstrap and masonry]

I'm using Bootstrap with Rails 4. I'm creating two columns with each_slice(). I tried the following, using the [Masonry Rails gem](https://github.com/kristianmandrup/masonry-rails), but it doesn't work yet:

```
<div id="masonry-container">
    <% @projects.each_slice(2) do |projects| %>
        <div class="col-md-6 box">
            <% projects.each do |project| %>
                  <p><%= project.name %></p>
            <% end %>
       </div>
    <% end %>
</div>
```

And I added this to application.js:

```
$(function(){
  $('#masonry-container').masonry({
      itemSelector: '.box',
  });
});
```

What am I doing wrong with Masonry?

In application.js, I have:

```
//= require masonry/masonry.min
```

And in application.css.scss, I have:

```
/*
*= require 'masonry/basic'
*/
```

Answer (score 0):

I got this to work by editing the CSS of:

```
#masonry-container {
  margin: 0 auto;
}

.box {
  width:450px;
}
```